# How to get public prime from DHE from TLS v1 DHE-RSA x.509 certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, tls, x509

I can view the certificate using

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.masaood.com:443 </dev/null

I can view the public key of a RSA, but cannot find any information for DHE:

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.masaood.com:443  </dev/null | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout

How do I view the prime number and base g of the DHE protocol in the certificate with OpenSSL or any information of the DHE shared key exchange?

Comment: There are no DH information in the certificate for this site and even if the would be they would not be used for DHE key exchange but only for DH key exchange. Apart from that a better place to ask such questions is probably security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from viewing it using Wireshark option, I found out it is possible to view the handshake protocol via [OpenSSL trace option](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:S_client(1)#OPTIONS)

> **Trace**: show verbose trace output of protocol messages. OpenSSL needs to be compiled with enable-ssl-trace for this option to work.